# Foreign Key update from JSON using ORMLite

Tags: java, android, gson, ormlite

I am using ORMLite within an Android application along side Gson and currently struggling with the following issue.

Within my app, there are multiple classes that make use of ORMLite/Gson, for simplicity I shall describe the issue using only two.

Say we have a class `Product`:

```
@SerializedName("product_id")
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "products")
public class Product {

    public Product() {
    }

    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private int id;

    // Generic stuff
    @DatabaseField
    @SerializedName("product_desc")
    private String desc;
    @DatabaseField
    @SerializedName("in_stock")
    private boolean inStock;
    @DatabaseField(unique = true)
    @SerializedName("product_name")
    private String name;

    // Issue occurs here
    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
    private Venue venue;

}
```

and we have a class "Venue`:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "venues")
public class Venue {

    public Venue() {
    }

    @SerializedName("venueid")
    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private int id;

    // Other Generic Junk
    @DatabaseField
    private String desc;
    @DatabaseField
    private String email;
    @DatabaseField
    private String fax;
    @DatabaseField
    @SerializedName("venue_name")
    private String name;
    @DatabaseField
    private String phoneNumber;

}
```

I use Gson to deserialize Json from a pre-written API and ORMLite populate the database with this data. An issue occurs as the API returns the **venue id** of the venue each product is associated with (e.g venueid = 1) and not a `Venue` object.

However, the database is already populated with these venues so `venueid = 1` refers to a real venue within the current database.

The trouble is getting ORMLite to understand this and update the `Venue` object within `Product` to be that of id = 1!

Can anyone think of a solution?

**EDIT:**

To better understand my issue, here is some sample Json:

```
[
    {
        "productid": 1,
        "venueid": 4,
        "product_name": "Jack Daniels",
        "in_stock": true,
        "orders_accepted": true,
     }
     ...
]
```

As you can see, I get an int for venueid and NOT a `Venue` object. Is there an easy way to convert it to it's corresponding venue without the large overhead of multiple queries

Comment: To better understand. You want that after Gson deserializazion venue is populated with the right object while your string has only its id?

Comment: Please see my edit, perhaps it would provide some clarity @trapo

Answer (score 0):

This is an high level answer based on assumption that:

- your API returns you also a Json string for every Venue object or
- you can easily get a Json string for every `Venue` object you have in your DB (sorry I do not know ORMLite at all, even if from its name, I can image what it does ;) ).

So, somehow build a little dictionary like a `Map<Integer, String>` where the int key is your venue id and value is Json string for that `Venue` object.

Then, when you get `Product` Json from API, do a simple string replacement using a regexp.
For example, you should transform:

```
{
  "productid": 1,
  "venueid": 4,
  "product_name": "Jack Daniels",
  "in_stock": true,
  "orders_accepted": true,
}
```

into:

```
{
  "productid":1,
  "venue":{
    "venueid":4,
    "desc":"aDesc",
    "email":"aEmail",
    "fax":"aFax",
    "venue_name":"aname",
    "phoneNumber":"aPhonenumber"
  },
  "product_name":"Jack Daniels",
  "in_stock":true,
  "orders_accepted":true
}
```

After string replacement you should be able to parse the updated Json string into your data structure without involving database anymore. Think this like something a "Json lookup".

If you can read Venue from DB, your query cost will be only a "select all" to fill the map, after that string replacement will occur in memory only.